# GTFS application (python)

Tags: python-3.x, command-line

I need to make a command line application which has two parameters:

the location of the input file, and
the location of the output file.
The input file is a GTFS (.txt) file.

The output file is a .shp file.

How should I do this?

Comment: You haven't show any of your code, if there is any.

Answer (score 1):

To get command line parameters:

```
% python3 your_script.py parameter1 parameter2
```

Where parameter1 and parameter2 are you input file and output file names:

```
import sys
parameters = sys.argv
#parameters now contains 3 strings:
#"your_script.py" in parameters[0]
#"parameter1" in parameters [1]
#"parameter2" in parameters [2]
```

So you can use the command line arguments as variables. To open the files:

```
in_file = open(parameters[1] + ".txt") #from your problem statement, it sounds
             #like your filenames don't include extensions. If they do, remove
             #the (+ ".txt") part

out_file = open(parameters[2] + ".shp", 'w')
```

For more information about I/O operations in Python, see [this link](https://www.guru99.com/reading-and-writing-files-in-python.html)